# Validate with REGEX alpha with support in many languages

Tags: java, regex

Hi guys I am working in a java validator library. My question is How can I validate inputs to be alpha (no alphanumeric) in many languages. I have the following REGEX:

```
public AlphaValidator() {
    super();
    this.rule = "^[a-zA-Z[*]]+$"; // its fine with : angel, world, bottle, etc.
}
```

Its ok, but If the library is implemented for spanish inputs or french ones maybe with words like : vi un ñandu or árbol do not match with the REGEX.

I was writting the special characters like :

```
private String getSpanishFilter() {
    return "-ñ-Ñ-á-Á-é-É-í-Í-ó-Ó-ú-Ú-ü-Ü";
}

private String getFrenchFilter() {
    return "â-à-ç-é-ê-ë-è-ï-î-ô-û-ù-Â-À-Ç-É-Ê-Ë-È-Ï-Î-Ô-Û-Ù";
}
```

But I think this is not the best solution. Any help?

Comment: you forget æ, Æ, œ, Œ in the french filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't understand why you have enclosed `*` inside a nested character class. That is nothing but union, and is as good as using just `*`. And to match unicode letters, you can use `\p{L}`.

And if you're already on Java 7, then you can use [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) flag, or embedded flag - `(?U)` with your given pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[*\\w&&[^\\d_]]+$", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

And if you're keeping regex as string, then use embedded flag as:

```
rule = "(?U)^[*\\w&&[^\\d_]]+$";
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot explain that point. I was thinking in replace [*] for the new characters from the other languages encapsulated in thoses methods.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the docs for [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)?

Under "Classes for Unicode scripts, blocks, categories and binary properties":

```
\p{IsAlphabetic}    An alphabetic character (binary property)
```

So your pattern could be:

```
"\\p{IsAlphabetic}+"
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way with `matches()`:

```
\\pL+    # no need to add anchors with matches() method
```

The shortest way with `find()`:

```
\\PL     # stop at the first non letter character
```

note: you can write `\\p{L}` and `\\P{L}` too, `\\pL` and `\\PL` are shortcuts.

But if you need to match only latin characters, it's better to use:

```
\\p{isLatin}+
```